# Permission error while installing Ubuntu alongside Windows 7

Tags: system-installation, wubi, log

I have tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 as the instructions tell me, but when I run the installer and it's towards the end, I get and error. Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/a55vqJE4

TL;DR: It says permission error

I just got this computer and want to put Ubuntu on it like my last.

Comment: It seems that the installer has trouble decompressing the file, perhaps due to a download error. Have you tried this more than once?

Comment: Yes I have tried it multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The first couple of times you experience [bug 862003](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/862003) (which means the install was actually successful). The last time you had the extraction error. Not sure about that.

My advice:

1. Download the `desktop CD ISO` from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)
2. Save it in the **same directory** as `wubi.exe` from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer)
3. Run `wubi.exe`. It will find the ISO and use it.

That avoids [bug 862003](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/862003) as well as the extraction error (and you only have to download the ISO once - plus you can use it to create an Ubuntu CD/USB).